# Import all data from Firebase Database into Mailchimp

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, mailchimp, newsletter

**Firebase** can be linked to **Mailchimp**, so I did. However, there is no way to import existing data. Only new ones will be inserted. Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the [Sync with Mailchimp](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/auth-mailchimp-sync/) extension for Firebase, which:

> Adds new users from Firebase Authentication to a specified Mailchimp audience.

Given that description, it seems that this extension is only used for new users that are added to Firebase.

If you want to also add your existing users to Mailchimp, you have a few options:

1. Write code to [list those users with the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users), and then add them to Mailchimp using the Mailchimp API. You can use the [source code of the extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/master/auth-mailchimp-sync) for inspiration.
2. [File a feature request on the extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/) to add support for this feature.